# how to Inline the div

Tags: html, css

Following is my div in which i am trying to create a square in a div , the problem i faced is that when ever i try to create a square then square goes to new line.

Example:

```
My [SQUARE] Should look like this // NO linebreak

But my // line automatically break
[SQUARE] 
/* line automatically break */ look like this
```

Note: I cannot use float to left and right and also i tried display:inline; but it didnot work. Kindly let me know how can i create a square inline to my content

```
<div style="width:10px; height:10px; border:1px solid #000; background:yellow;"></div>
```

Comment: Is that html for your square?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand this is what's happening:

```
Your content
[SQUARE]
More content
```

**Instead of**

```
Your content [SQUARE] more content
```

Have you tried `display: inline-block;`

Also, check that the containing div is able to fit all this content in a single line.

**Edit:** Remember that `display: block` is the **DEFAULT** property for (most) elements, and this will force them on a new line. So to change this you override the default yourself by setting a custom `display:` property.

For a list of them all go to: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display

Comment: okay issue is being resolved thanks... moreover how can i vertically set aligning of square?

Comment: If you need to vertically align the square then you should see my answer to this persons post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281151/center-small-div-in-big-div-vertically-and-horizontally/14281279#14281279 it also has a link to a jsfiddle explaining everything as well http://jsfiddle.net/4Gjxk/1/

Answer (score 4):

try this by adding `display:inline-block` into your code

`<div style="display: inline-block; width:10px; height:10px; border:1px solid #000; background:yellow;"></div>`

Answer (score 4):

If i got your problem right:

Try to set `display:inline-block;` within the styletag of the div.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply the display: inline property to all elements that you want on the same row,
or else it wont work, and if you want you can then apply float properties.