# Center small div in big div vertically and horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code is as follows:

```
<div id="bigDiv">
  <div id="smallDiv">DD</div>
</div>
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
#bigDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;

}

#smallDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I want to center the small div vertically and horizontally inside the big div.  The horizontal works, but the vertical doesn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/4Gjxk/

Comment: if you don't care about IE7, just add `display: table-cell` to your `#bigDiv {` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is the most straight-forward solution with the least amount of CSS.  Since 100 / 300 = ~.33 you can use a 33% margin like so:

```
#bigDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

#smallDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 33%;
}
```

Here's the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Gjxk/2/).

Comment: Creative solution! - But in today's age a few more lines of CSS (a couple of Kb is really nothing to download). Not trying to discredit you in favor of my answer, since I wouldn't have thought of this in a very long time. Once again, nice answer!

Answer (score 8):

Read this: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

If you cannot be bothered reading do this:

```
    #bigDiv {

      position: relative; /* Needed for position: absolute to be related to this element and not body */

      border: 1px solid red;
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

And change the other to:

```
#smallDiv {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

}
```

**Here is the updated jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4Gjxk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
#smallDiv{
    position:absolute;//? relative?
    top:45%;
    left:45%;
}
```

That should be just about right but I'm sure someone will come up with a better method. Obviously you could also do pixels so `top:100px;left:100px;` Will work also perhaps better in your case :).

Answer (score 0):

Try with absolute positioning. You just have to know the width of the element to place it right in center.

```
  #bigDiv {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 300px;
}

  #smallDiv {
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 100px;
        left: 50%;
        margin: -50px auto 0 -50px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: 100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to #smallDiv:

```
margin-top: 100px;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it without knowing the exact size of the boxes (if they may change) this is a slightly hacky way of doing it: http://jsfiddle.net/gXbqm/

```
#bigDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:table-cell

}

#smallDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align:center;
}
```

If you know that those divs will always be 100x100 and 300x300 though, Jonathan.cone's solution is cleaner